# Visual Studio 2017 auto installs Java SE 1.8, does that come licensed?

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I noticed that in January of 2019 Oracle will require the JavaSDK to be licensed for any updates.  I notice that Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise auto-installs this Java SE SDK onto my computer as part of the Xamarin install package (I'm assuming).  Does this mean that over time and in the background the JDK might be updated and my company will be hit with a lawsuit for having un-licensed software on my computer?

[image]

Comment: could you check if VS comes with Ope JDK?
**java -version 2>&1 | grep "OpenJDK Runtime" | wc -l**
returns 0 if using Oracle JDK, 1 if using OpenJDK

Comment: with VS2017 15.9 Microsoft switches to OpenJDK to avoid license issues with JRE

Answer (score -1):

Java Development Kit is free to us until version 10.
JDK11 is the first one, for which you have to pay something.